# css overflow hidden to display images that are within defined "window" div

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, hidden

I'm trying to setup the css for a native javascript animation.  There are going to be several images that enter a "window" which is 600px.  As one image slides in or out, the only visible part will be the part of the images that is within the window.  I've had several attempts at setting this up with css before I start javascript animating, which include things like overflow:hidden on the rotator div and setting it's width, however that doesn't seem to work.

```
    #rotator {
        width: 600px;
        height: 320px;
        background: #131313;
        /*text-align: left;*/
        /*display: inline-block;*/
        overflow: hidden;
        /*position: relative;*/
        /*float: left;*/

    }
    .box_wrapper {
        width: 450px;
        /*position: absolute;*/
        display: inline-block;
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
    }
<div id="rotator">
    <div class="box_wrapper">
        <h4>Header1</h4>
        <img src="../img/kat_3.jpg" /><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="box_wrapper box_2">
        <h4>Header2</h4>
        <img src="../img/kat_2.jpg" /><br/>
    </div>  
</div>
```

The images either fully show up or not at all when messing with the css properties.

Comment: Did you try setting `overflow: hidden` on `#rotator`

Comment: yes that is shown in my code

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need set the width or height of the images, so they can be scaled into the the divs.

```
<style>
  #rotator {
    width: 600px;
    height: 320px;
    background: #131313;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .box_wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

$('.box_wrapper').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this), $img = $el.find('img'), fixedRatio = 600 / 320,
    ratio = $img.width() / $img.height(),
    offset = $img.offset().top - $el.offset().top;
  if (ratio > fixedRatio) {
    $img.width($el.width()).height('auto');
  } else {
    $img.height($el.height() - offset).width('auto');
  }
});
```

Comment: that didn't work for me... can you explain a bit more about why that idea might work and point to some examples? Also no jQuery please

Comment: the idea is to limit the images' width/height, e.g. if an image's real size is 1000px/800px, and you need display it in a block with fixed width 450px, you can obviously assign a property 'width' on the img tag <img src="..." width="450px"/>, so the whole image can show then but with a smaller size. if you know the real size of those images, you can generate the img html code with property 'width' or 'height' at the server side, if you don't, ajust it via js code.